# What Hybris Does when we do Modelservice.Save()?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

While I am saving a model using `ModelService.save()`, it is throwing

```
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.InterceptorException: [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.UniqueAttributesInterceptor@555528e4]:ambiguous unique keys
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.UniqueAttributesInterceptor.onValidate(UniqueAttributesInterceptor.java:158)
```

What I understand is it is happening because it is trying to `INSERT` and if it can DO **INSERT_UPDATE** then the problem can be resolved. I don't want to make Legacy Mode ON so please provide me a solution where I can do `INSERT_UPDATE` through `ModelService.save()` method.

If ModelService.save() is doing INSERT_UPDATE then why the error is coming.

Comment: Add the code snippet. Look like, you are trying to insert the same record again.

Answer (score 6):

The ModelService in hybris realizes a different functionality than you expect. The model service supports:

**Creating a new item**

```
ProductModel newProduct = modelService.create(ProductModel.class);
```

**Writing changes to an item**

```
modelService.save(product);
```

**Deleting an item**

```
modelSerivce.remove(product);
```

**Refreshing an item, when changes are made by a different context**

```
modelService.refresh(product);
```

---

**Retrieving data from the database**

When you want to change an existing item, you need to get it from the database first. There are multiple opportunities to retrieve existing items. Consider the following cases:

**Retrieve an existing product, user, category...**
For most of the standard hybris items there are services to retrieve Use ProductService, UserService, CategoryService... Now use ModelService to save the changes made to that model.

```
ProductModel product = productService.getProductForCode("myEAN");
product.setMyCustomAttribute("ABC");
modelService.save(product);
```

**Editing a custom itemtype/itemtype without hybris prepared service**
When hybris does not provide a service to get the item from the database, you need to implement that service yourself. There are multiple opportunities to do so.

**FlexibleSearchService**

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("id", "123");
String query = "SELECT {pk} FROM {MyCustomType} WHERE {id} LIKE ?id";
SearchResult<MyCustomTypeModel> result = flexibleSearchService.search(query, params);
List<MyCustomTypeModel> myCustomTypesWithId = result.getResult();
```

**GenericSearchService**

```
GenericSearchField idField = new GenericSearchField(MyCustomTypeModel._TYPECODE, MyCustomTypeModel.ID);
GenericCondition condition = GenericCondition.createConditionForValueComparison(idField, Operator.EQUAL, "123");
GenericQuery query = new GenericQuery(MyCustomTypeModel._TYPECODE, condition);
SearchResult<MyCustomTypeModel> searchResult = genericSearchService.search(query);
List<MyCustomTypeModel> myCustomTypesWithId = searchResult.getResult();
```

These are just the most prominent ones. Consult hybris help/wiki pages for more. Which one you prefer is up to you. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

It is recommend to wrap this data access functionality in own classes. Classes that search the database for items are called DAO (Data Access Object).

Answer (score 4):

Look like, you are trying to insert the UNIQUE record again.

### To update the record

- You have to first fetch the existing model obj(which contain pk) from db. For that, You can use flexible search, [get model by example](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/models-by-example-in-hybris-flexible-Search.html) etc.
- Now update the attribute which you want
- Save `modelService.save(obj)`

### To Insert new entry

- create the instance of model and set the values

  `final MyModel obj = modelService.create(MyModel.class);`

  `obj.setId("unique");`
- Save it `modelService.save(product);`

Answer (score 0):

In hybris if you set UNIQUE while defining an attribute in Item.xml 
,then the value must be UNIQUE otherwise error throw during import

Suppose attribute userid has define UNIQUE=true for item i.e.

```
<attribute qualifier="userid" type="java.lang.String">
                        <description>user id of user.</description>
                        <modifiers unique="true"/>
                        <persistence type="property"/>
</attribute>
```

Now you import data through ImpEx

```
INSERT_UPDATE EveryreplyUserAddress;userid[unique=true];street;state
;0001;delhi;delhi
```

If you try to INSERT_UPDATE again with same userid as 0001 then it will throw error because in Item you have define userid is UNIQUE
IMPORTANT:
During import UNIQUENESS is check by UniqueAttributesInterceptor.
But you can still import your data through by making legacy mode to ON

So after make legacy mode ON call of Interceptor will SKIPP then value will insert into database

> *-Items.xml

```
<attribute qualifier="userid" type="java.lang.String">
                        <description>user id of user.</description>
                        <modifiers unique="true"/>
                        <persistence type="property"/>
</attribute>
```

By using ModelService if you will save item then again interceptor will to check UNIQUNESS

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but I believe that INSERT_UPDATE will work(update based on the unique key). Only INSERT will crash because of UniqueAttributeInterceptor.

Comment: I also believe that in the newer versions of hybris the legacy mode will skip indeed the interceptor, but a unique constraint is present also at DB level so it will crash anyway